# Transmission-deamon just stop the flux

Tags: c, unix, p2p, transmission, torrent

I'll like to stop the **P2P flux** when I'll call the command line, without the stop the **transmission deamon webserver.**

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at my question.

- I used the command line of **transmission-remote**.
- I used node js for test if the network card is ready and if the network(internet) is ready.
- I used the network-manager and the following command nmcli for conditional loop.